# Comparing Spring Gateway Routes without false negatives

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an [app](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287625/is-this-how-you-do-a-dynamic-spring-cloud-gateway) and want to write some tests. Since it's a reactive app, a Spring-powered Gateway, I almost certainly need to use `StepVerifier`. My code may include something like this:

```java
StepVerifier.create(routeLocator.getRoutes())
            .expectNext(expectedRoute)
            .expectComplete()
            .verify();
```

The thing is `expectNext()` in turn invokes `equals()` of `Route`

```java
// Route's equals()

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Route route = (Route) o;
        return this.order == route.order && Objects.equals(this.id, route.id) && Objects.equals(this.uri, route.uri)
                && Objects.equals(this.predicate, route.predicate)
                && Objects.equals(this.gatewayFilters, route.gatewayFilters)
                && Objects.equals(this.metadata, route.metadata);
    }
```

which in turn invokes `equals()` of `AsyncPredicate` (the type of `Route`'s `predicate` field) which it doesn't override and inherits from `Object` ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/3236)). As a result, this test wouldn't pass due to a false negative:

```java
class RouteEqualityTest {

    @Test
    void testTwoIdenticalRouteAreEqual() {
        assertThat(getRouteBuilderStub().build()).isEqualTo(getRouteBuilderStub().build());
    }

    private Route.AsyncBuilder getRouteBuilderStub() {
        return Route.async()
                .id("123")
                .uri("https://example.com")
                .predicate(exchange -> exchange.getRequest()
                        .getPath()
                        .value()
                        .equals("/test-path"));
    }
}
```

I wondered whether I could write a custom `AsyncPredicate` implementation with the aim of overriding its `equals()`, then invoke `asyncPredicate()` instead of `predicate()` and pass my custom impementation (`predicate()` first converts the argument to `DefaultAsyncPredicate` and then invokes `asyncPredicate()` on it). However, I still face the challenge of comparing two `Predicate`s which, apparently, I can't do (at least, not with lambdas)

```java
    class DefaultAsyncPredicate<T> implements AsyncPredicate<T> {
        /*
        Suppose I copy paste it into my custom `MyAsyncPredicate` and try to
        override `equals()`. How do I compare two Predicates?
        */
        private final Predicate<T> delegate;

        public DefaultAsyncPredicate(Predicate<T> delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public Publisher<Boolean> apply(T t) {
            return Mono.just(delegate.test(t));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.delegate.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
            if (delegate instanceof GatewayPredicate) {
                GatewayPredicate gatewayPredicate = (GatewayPredicate) delegate;
                gatewayPredicate.accept(visitor);
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
// doesn't pass – you can't meaningfully compare two Predicate lambdas

    @Test
    void testPredicateEquality() {
        Assertions.assertThat((Predicate<Object>) o -> true).isEqualTo((Predicate<Object>) o -> true);
    }
```

I may resort to some kludge like avoiding comparing `Predicate`s in my tests by setting the same `AsyncPredicate` reference for both `Route` instances before invoking `expectNext()`. But then my tests wouldn't be thorough. What if, for example, one `Route`'s `AsyncPredicate` matches `/right-path` and another one's `Predicate` matches `/wrong-path`? Such test wouldn't catch that

How can (should) I resolve this conundrum?

## UPD

I came up with this workaround, but it's not perfect. A web exchange predicate is about so much more than simply a request path

```java
    private static Route.AsyncBuilder getRouteBuilderStub() {
        return Route.async()
                .id("123")
                .uri("https://example.com")
                .asyncPredicate(PathOnlyAsyncPredicate.from("/test-path"));
    }
```

```java
public class PathOnlyAsyncPredicate implements AsyncPredicate<ServerWebExchange> {
    private final RequestPath path;

    private PathOnlyAsyncPredicate(String path) {
        this.path = RequestPath.parse(path, "");
    }

    public static AsyncPredicate<ServerWebExchange> from(String path) {
        return new PathOnlyAsyncPredicate(path);
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<Boolean> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.just(exchange.getRequest().getPath().equals(path));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PathOnlyAsyncPredicate that = (PathOnlyAsyncPredicate) o;
        return path.equals(that.path);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(path);
    }
}
```